# Utf8 accents in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

i tried to read a vcf file with utf8 encoding, with the result is:

```
{
        "name": "=4A=61=76=69=65=72=20=4C=75=6A=C3=A1=6E",
        "tel": "2814682382"
},
```

the problem are accents chars, for example `áéíóú`.

How to convert `name` into a valid utf-8 string?.

In the above example the string must be `Javier Luján`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Quoted Printable.

You can install [mimielib](https://github.com/andris9/mimelib) and use like below:

```
var mimelib = require("mimelib");

json = {
    "name": "=4A=61=76=69=65=72=20=4C=75=6A=C3=A1=6E",
    "tel": "2814682382"
};

name = mimelib.decodeQuotedPrintable(json.name);

console.log(name); // This will print Javier Luján
```